# How to Print a long String in Allure Report using @Step Annotation?

Tags: java, allure

I want to print a long string value in the allure report. I am using step annotation in my framework as below:
But, the message value is too long and it prints as dot dot in `allure report`.
Can anyone please provide a solution to this?

```
@Step ("LOG.INFO : {0}")
public static void info(String message){
System.out.println(message);
}
```

**Expected** :

```
 LOG.INFO : LDTP Locator Object List: [pane0, mnu0, ukn0, mnu1, 
    mnuOpenlinkinnewtab, mnuOpenlinkinnewwindow, mnuOpenlink, 
    mnuRefresh, mnusavelinkas]
```

**Actual**  :

```
 LOG.INFO : LDTP Locator Object List: 
 [pane0, mnu0, ukn0, mnu1, mnuOpenlinkinnewtab, 
 mnuOpenlinkinnewwindow, mnuOpenlinki...
```

Comment: what adaptor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For Allure 1 maximum step title length is 120. To override the value you can use `allure.max.title.length` system property. But note that long titles significantly increase report generation time.